# Differences between Sphinx local and readthedocs.org

Tags: python-sphinx

I have created a set of documentation for my `Django` app using `Sphinx`. I use `readthedocs.org` to create a public version of that documentation. This works well but for one oddity. On `readthedocs.org` some of my documentation generates differently from a local build. For example for my `models.py` I created `models.rst`, which looks like this:

``````
Models
======

.. automodule:: my_app.models

Agents
------

Agent
`````
.. autoclass:: Agent
   :members:

etc...
``````

For a local build this creates a document with model names as titles, their docstring and their members with docstrings where a `#: comment...` was added.

However on `readthedocs.org` only a title entry for each model is generated and nothing more.

It appears as if `readthedocs.org` ignores the `automodule` and `autoclass` directives.

Initially I thought this was caused by the difference in theme (I use the `bootstrap` theme locally and the `readthedocs` theme on `readthedocs.org`), but after setting up a `virtualenv` on `readthedocs.org` and using the `bootstrap` theme there as well, nothing changed. The build completes, but documentation for my models remains absent.

Locally I use `Sphinx 1.2.2`. I'm not sure which version is used on readthedocs.org but I presume a 1.2.x release.

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has bugged me for a week - at least in my case the solution was simple:

In the "Advanced Settings" of the readthedocs.org dashboard you can specify a `requirements.txt` file. In this file I had not specified the PyQt5 module that was imported in some of my modules - adding the module immediately fixed my problem.

For all those modules, only a title string was generated while all the others rendered fine. Why the build process on readthedocs.org fails silently and reports a successful build beats me. I haven't found a way yet to make the build process more verbose or to check the log files.

See also [Debug / logging info for build process on readthedocs.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218699/debug-logging-info-for-build-process-on-readthedocs-org)

And especially the (better) answer under [Sphinx automodule works offline but not through readthedocs.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246562/sphinx-automodule-works-offline-but-not-through-readthedocs-org)