# Sphinx automodule works offline but not through readthedocs.org

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I cant seem to get ReadTheDocs to show a any module's :members:, for instance in my local html i get:

```
MODULE
module.Beta(r, theta, beta)
    evaluates Beta at point
```

but after pushing to github the readthedocs doc only says:

```
MODULE
```

No error appears and when I build it to html locally it runs without warnings.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Build logs in *readthedocs.org* dashboard.

Most likely you are using third party packages which fail to import on readthedocs.org because you are not providing correct `requirements.txt` file.

[Please see FAQ here](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc).

Comment: This is the problem indeed, still not working but I'm on the right track, thanks!

Comment: You can also provide stub modules in your `conf.py` using Mock: http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules

Comment: Yeah, I finally used that. Works fine now thank you!